# Could a question about investment in UK equities and Brexit be on topic here?

Tags: discussion

I haven't participated in this stack before and don't have a handle on what sorts of questions are on or off topic here.

I'm based in he UK, in my early thirties and currently have a good pension with a reputable company that allows me to choose which funds my pension is invested in  (I get a breakdown of the risk level and the types of investments these funds make).

Looking at my current investments I can see that my pension fund currently consists of:

- **46.42% UK equities**
- 42.68% Global equity
- 4.49% Cash or Equivalents
- 3.5% Other
- 2.92% Bonds

With Brexit potentially just around the corner (and a lot of market uncertainty) should I be considering moving my pension into funds that are less reliant on UK equities?

I'm politically pre-disposed to thinking that Brexit is a terrible idea and will go terribly (I really hate that it's happening at all) but don't want to let this cloud my judgement when making financial decisions.

Is there any way that a question relating to this could be on-topic here? Any tips on how to express some of this in a way that isn't merely opinion based would be helpful?

Answer (score 7):

It could be if you tie it to personal finance and investment decisions. Just avoid getting too political or delving into economics.